# Laravel pluck fails to get value from load relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I need to return just an array of the `name` values for each of my roles. My `roles` is a `hasMany` relationship. This is currently how I'm trying to do it, but the returned result is unchanged, what am I missing?

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Request $request, Company $company)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $company);

    if ($request->boolean('with_roles')) {
        $company = $company->load(['roles' => function ($query) {
            $query->pluck('name');
        }]);
    }

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($company);
}
```

gives me:

```php
{
    "model": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "contact_first_name": "John",
        "created_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:48.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:48.000000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "is_deleting": false,
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "company_id": 1,
                "name": "accountant",
                "guard_name": "api",
                "created_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:59.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:59.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "company_id": 1,
                "name": "admin",
                "guard_name": "api",
                "created_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:48.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:48.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "company_id": 1,
                "name": "affiliate",
                "guard_name": "api",
                "created_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:56.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:56.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "company_id": 1,
                "name": "affiliate_manager",
                "guard_name": "api",
                "created_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:55.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:55.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "company_id": 1,
                "name": "buyer",
                "guard_name": "api",
                "created_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:58.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:58.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "company_id": 1,
                "name": "guest",
                "guard_name": "api",
                "created_at": "2023-02-15T09:46:02.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-15T09:46:02.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "company_id": 1,
                "name": "user",
                "guard_name": "api",
                "created_at": "2023-02-15T09:46:00.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-02-15T09:46:00.000000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I expect to see:

```
{
    "model": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "contact_first_name": "John",
        "created_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:48.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-15T09:45:48.000000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "is_deleting": false,
        "roles": [
            "accountant",
            "admin",
            "affiliate"
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pluck` doesn't modify the original relationship, it only returns an array. Try this one :

```php
public function show(Request $request, Company $company)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $company);

    $result = $company->toArray();

    if ($request->boolean('with_roles')) {
        $result['roles'] = $company->roles()->pluck('name')->toArray();
    }

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($result);
}
```